# C++ Inserting a class into a map container

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, dictionary

I have a map in C++ and I wish to input my class as the value, and a string as the key.
When I try to, I get an error `'Scene_Branding' : illegal use of this type as an expression`
I get an illegal use of this type as an expression, and I can't seem to find out why. Here is some code.

```
 string CurrentScene = "Scene_Branding";
 map<string, Scene> Scenes;
 Scenes.insert(std::make_pair("Scene_Branding", Scene_Branding));  //<-- Illegal Error parameter 2
```

and here is Scene Branding header..

```
#ifndef Scene_Branding_H
#define Scene_Branding_H

#include "Scene.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class Scene_Branding : Scene
{
public:
 Scene_Branding();
 ~Scene_Branding();
 void Draw();
};

#endif
```

and here is Scene header..

```
#ifndef Scene_H
#define Scene_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Scene
{
public:
 Scene();
 ~Scene();
 virtual void Draw();

};

#endif
```

and here is there cpp files.

Scene cpp.

```
#include "Scene.h"

Scene::Scene()
{

}
Scene::~Scene()
{

}
void Scene::Draw(){
 std::cout << "Hey";
}
```

Scene_Branding cpp

```
#include "Scene_Branding.h"

Scene_Branding::Scene_Branding()
{

}

Scene_Branding::~Scene_Branding()
{

}

void Scene_Branding::Draw()
{
 std::cout << "Drawing from Scene_branding";
}
```

Comment: both answers are correct in pointing out that you need an instance of Scene_Branding not just the type. one more hint make your base class destructor virtual

Comment: Do you really mean to use private inheritance?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First, don't store objects themselves in the map, store pointers to your objects.

Second, you need to give an instance of Scene_Branding to std::make_pair, not the class itself.

EDIT:
Here's how you go about storing pointers:

```
 string CurrentScene = "Scene_Branding";
 map<string, Scene*> Scenes;
 Scenes.insert(std::make_pair("Scene_Branding", new Scene_Branding()));
```

But, since you asked this type of question, i recommend you read a good c++ book for further grasping of concepts like pointers.

Comment: Storing objects is fine as long as the object's class is final.

Comment: Aha, I tried this, but I was mistakenly placing Scene_Branding .. anyway, thanks.

Comment: @kennytm could you clarify a little. What does it mean "as long as object's class is final? You mean [final keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final)? And why this final will do?

Comment: @IvanTalalaev "final" means there are no subclasses to the `Scene` class. If there are subclasses then using `map<string, Scene>` may cause object-slicing. A final class prevents this situation.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
Scenes.insert(std::make_pair("Scene_Branding", Scene_Branding()));
```

Comment: This works, but the code is not as intended and cout is outputting Hey, and not Drawing from Scene_Branding.. hmm but thanks for the fix.

Comment: This is because an instance of Scene is stored in the map, not an instance of Scene_Branding. This is called object slicing, briefly it causes you to lose information declared in Scene_Branding. Storing pointers will not cause this issue.

Comment: How would I go about handing it a pointer? I seem to just get errors such as 
error C2664: 'Scene::Scene(const Scene &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Scene_Branding (__cdecl *const )(void)' to 'const Scene &'

Comment: -1 because of slicing bug. I think you didn't see that the OP wants a container of polymorphic objects. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think you don't want to do that.

1. there is no runtime type-mapping in C++, you store objects, not types.
2. you cannot store polymorphic types in STL containers, use `boost::ptr_map` instead if it is your wish

So, the "new" code:

```
class Scene
{
public:
  virtual ~Scene();                  // Virtual Destructor, it's a base class
  virtual Scene* clone() const = 0;  // Polymorphic construction
private:
  // whatever you wish
};

class Scene_Branding: public Scene
{
public:
  virtual Scene_Branding* clone() const { return new Scene_Branding(); }
};
```

And the new way to store those:

```
const std::string SceneBrandingKey = "Scene_Branding";

typedef boost::ptr_map<std::string, Scene> scenes_type;

scenes_type Scenes;
Scenes.insert(SceneBrandingKey, new Scene_Branding());
```

And you can use it thusly:

```
Scenes["Scene_Branding"].process(); // Note: use '.' not '->'
```

The nice thing about [Boost Pointer Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) is that it's been meant for polymorphic types, with exception safety and all, and yet mimics the behavior / interface of the STL so that you are not lost :)

Comment: I think OP is a little newbie to be diving into boost yet.

Comment: I'm not sure, but IMHO instead of
virtual Scene_Branding* clone() const 
there should be
virtual Scene* clone() const 
;-)

Comment: It's funny how everybody thinks C++ newbies need to learn to do things the error-prone manual way, before using libraries that make life easier.

Comment: +1 After the OP learns about the pitfalls of manual memory management, he/she will come to appreciate shared_ptr and ptr_container.

Comment: Of course, things that make life easier are better but, in order to use high level stuff efficiently, one must understand low level stuff, don't you think? Don't give a lamborghini to a new driver.

Comment: @Dominic: no, it's correct because a `Scene_Branding*` is convertible to a `Scene*` (it's called covariant return). It means that by invoking the `virtual` method you get a `Scene*` but if you explicitly use the `Scene_Branding::clone` then you obtain a `Scene_Branding*` > if you have more type information, you get a more precise type in return :)

Comment: @erelender: I only partially agree. I am not going to delve into template metaprogramming or preprocessor programming yet, it's too soon for the OP. On the other hand, why should I not show easy-to-use libraries ? I don't understand why people keep on teaching about `char*` manipulations in C++ because `std::string` are more elaborate when you have strings in just about every other language...

Comment: @Matthieu: I only partially agree also :). When you teach someone how to use std::string, he only learns how to use std::string. On the other hand teaching char* manupilations allows him to apply the concept of pointer manupilation to other types as well. I think learning a language should be about how stuff works under the hood, not how to use stuff. If one learns how stuff works, others will follow.

Answer (score 2):

You need pointers in class when use generic map containers else, the result is possible a new object empty of your class... with pointers works!

```
std::map<std::string, Type*> map_;
```

### Insert

```
map_["key"] = *Type;
```

NOTE: if -fpermisive flag to compiler is not set you need pass *Type not const when insert in the map_ container.

Best Regards,

Javier,